# get corresponding OrderDate for max(OrderPrice)

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

An example:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

In the above example, how to get corresponding OrderDate for max(OrderPrice)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use HAVING without GROUP BY.

```
SELECT OrderDate FROM table_name HAVING MAX(column_name);
```